# Does Google Chrome blocking Java mean that a Java EE based web server wont work on Chrome?

Tags: jakarta-ee

Hi: According to [recent news](http://news.thewindowsclub.com/google-launches-chrome-42-npapi-push-notifications-76969/), Google Chrome will stop supporting Java soon.

I am studying web server design for an exam, and have to choose a solution. 
So far the default solution was "J2EE" as the architecture for the system, but I am thinking of replacing this with a LAMP platform instead because of the recent news.

Would the apps or functionality provided by a J2EE web server be "blocked" by Chrome, or am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: Chrome is blocking **applets**.

Comment: thank you all for the answers. Dont quite understand the downvotes, as you can see from the question Im a bit confused and not familiar with Java and read a lot before asking this question, couldnt think of anywhere else better to ask about it. I apologize if it was not appropriate.

Comment: You should understand the difference between server-side and client-side code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are understanding something wrong.

The browser communicates with a web server using HTTP. Whether the server application is written in Java, C, PHP, Perl or whatever is completely irrelevant, and the browser doesn't even know, or have any way to know. It sends HTTP requests, and receives HTTP responses, and that's all what matters.

Java applets are a completely different matter. They consist in downloading a Java application and executing this application inside the browser. That's what Chrome is blocking.

Note that the correct term is Java EE. J2EE is obsolete for a long time.